# Can't get Bitmap from ImageView as a BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, android-bitmap

In my Android - Kotlin application , I'm trying to get the bitmap out of an image to use it's `colorPallete`, here is the `ImageView` in my `XML` file:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dressImage_1"
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="123dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon" />
```

and here is how i add an Image to it :

```
Picasso.get().load(dress.image1).into(mDressImage1)
```

all goes fine to here.

**Note**:`dress.image1` returns an URL

After this, when I try to get the `bitmap` from the `imageView` this way :

```
        val bitmap = (mDressImage1?.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
```

it simply crashes. with nothing at the `logcat`

**UPDATE** 
it gave me the error `null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

pointing at the line `val bitmap = (mDressImage1?.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap`

Comment: Maybe this will help: Look into BitmapFactory.decodeResource https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
val bitmap = (mDressImage1?.drawable as? BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
```